# How to correctly explain that I’m able to work with different time zones

Tags: phrases

I'm looking for a remote job and I want to specify that I'm flexible regarding the time zone (so I can work according to almost any work hours ... German, US etc.) How does one write that correctly?

Comment: You are ready to work anywhere and anytime. Time and place are not barriers for you to work.

Comment: Available twenty-four hours a day.

Comment: A more reasonable way to put it is to say you're willing to flex your schedule.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Can I somehow specify that I'm willing to flex my schedule according to customer's work hours/time zone?

Comment: "Willing to flex schedule as needed"

Comment: As a request foe writing advice rather than about how say grammar works in a certain case or the actual sense of a given word in given context, this is better asked on Writing.SE.

Comment: to  work across time zones

Answer (score 1):

“My flexible schedule has allowed me to work with clients in different time zones, (ie. Germany, US).” Then add something short about how the time zones don’t affect communication and deadlines due to your time management skills.

You can word it differently but at least it’s something to start with, also write/speak as if you’ve already had clients. I refer to old employers as clients I’ve worked with. It also helps when it comes to speaking on experience instead of making something up.

Be sure to use affirmative, short statements. Summarize until you can’t anymore! Keep it short and sweet. Be confident, never desperate. Remember they need you as much as you need them!

I had this same question and answered it answering yours lol

if have more questions feel to reach out.

Good Luck